# Point-free way to map the values of the values in a seq

Tags: clojure

What is a simpler way I can write this:

```
(map #(map first %) [[[1 2] [3 4]] [[5 6]]])
 => ((1 3) (5))
```

Usually there are simpler ways to do this. I'm just not sure what.

I'm looking for a point free solution. Specifically this part `(map #(map first %) coll)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A point-free function expressing this would be:

```
(def firsts (partial map #(map first %)))
```

or to go fully point free:

```
(def firsts (partial map (partial map first)))
```

Used like:

```
(firsts [[[1 2] [3 4]] [[5 6]]])
```

Whether or not this is "simplified" though is subjective. I prefer the non-point-free version myself.

Comment: I like this solution `(def firsts (partial map (partial map first)))`. Thanks!